# Solaris に Redis を導入するには？

Tags: redis, solaris

レンタルサーバで使用しているOSがOracle Solarisというものなのですが、
そこにRedisを導入したいです。
yumやapt-getが使えず、どうしたらよいか困っています。

Comment: 参考: [CSWredis - Solaris package](https://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWredis/)

Answer (score 1):

yum や apt はそれぞれ対応したLinuxディストリビューション向けに用意されたコマンドなので、
別のOSでは当然ながら使えません。
(`yum` はCentOS/RHEL系、`apt` はDebian/Ubuntu系ディストリビューションのコマンド)

Redis に関しては [ソースコードも公開されている](https://redis.io/download) ので、自力でコンパイルを行うか、もしくはコメント欄で @metropolis さんが紹介している通り、Solaris 向けに用意されたパッケージ管理の仕組みを使ってインストールする方法もあります (パッケージとして用意されている場合に限る)。

Solaris でのパッケージ管理(pkgadd)等について、詳しくは以下のリンク先等を参考にしてください。

[パッケージコマンドによるソフトウェアパッケージの管理 - Solaris のシステム管理 (基本編)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24845_01/html/819-0378/ewbej.html#swmgrpkgscli-23)

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認してみます。